# Why does `equals` not compare string and string array?

Tags: java, equals

I'm comparing the input from a `TextEdit` with a answer from the "answerList". Now I'm wondering: Why does the `.equals()` not compare the "uinput" `String`? Could someone explain this to me and put it in use in the code?

Thanks in advance and have a good day!

```
package ...

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView view1;
public String uinput;
public EditText edit1;
public TextView score_view;
public int score = 0;

public String[] questionList = {
        "lux, luces",
        "munus, munera",
        "neglere",
};

public String[] answerList = {
        "(dag)licht, dag",
        "taak",
        "verwaarlozen",
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.edit1 = findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    this.view1 = findViewById(R.id.view1);
    this.score_view = findViewById(R.id.score_view);
    this.uinput = edit1.getText().toString();
    view1.setText(questionList[0]);
}

    public void check(View view) {
        if (uinput.equals(answerList[0])) {
            edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
            score++;
            score_view.setText(score);
        } else {
            edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Is you question why in the `check` method the `uinput.equals(answerList[0])` might not succeed? If so, it is likely because unless you set the `uinput` to the updated value of `edit1.getText()` elsewhere, it only has the value when it was first created, which would be an empty String. Try printing the the value of `uinput` before the test in the `check` method. If I have not understood the issue, please elaborate the specific issue you are seeing by providing current results and expected results.

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's question concerned a comparison of the `uinput` to an element in the array `questionList`. In the `check` method, the comparison was performed against the `uinput`, but the value of `uinput` was not being updated prior to the check.

```
public void check(View view) {
    // ADD HERE: update the value of the input
    uinput = edit1.getText().toString();

    if (uinput.equals(answerList[0])) {
        edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
        score++;
        score_view.setText(score);
    } else {
        edit1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove **this** keyword

```
......
edit1 = findViewById(R.id.edit1);
view1 = findViewById(R.id.view1);
score_view = findViewById(R.id.score_view);

......
```

add this in OnClick() method

```
uinput = edit1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Why would removing `this` make a difference?

Comment: because this key word referencing the context of the activity here. which is actually redundant

Comment: Hey, thank for the respons. I still get a false return from the method when I remove the `this` keyword? And how does redundancy makes the method return false?

Comment: Redundant or not, how would removing `this` solve the OP's issue? I don't see how this answer addresses the OP's question.

Comment: void Check(View) is his onClick() method. right? show what are you entering in the editText at run time?

Comment: I'm adding the correct answer for the 'question': "(dag)licht, dag"

Comment: ok then you should get the value from edit text inside the on click method. i have updated the answer check